# Better way to parse a string on PHP side?

Tags: php

I'm passing a javascript variable in my PHP form that gets passed as formatted below:

```
<form onsubmit='$("#crop_cords").val($.param(c).toString()); return true;' id="process_image_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

crop_cords='x=50&y=50&x2=400&y2=400&w=350&h=350'
```

Is there a better way to parse the value for crop_cords on the server side or do I need to use split and/or explode? I was hoping to find a cleaner solution. The result should look like this:

```
x=50
y=50
x2=400
y2=400
w=350
h=350
```

Comment: By the way, you have to encode `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` before outputting, something like: `<form action="<?php  echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$crop_cords='x=50&y=50&x2=400&y2=400&w=350&h=350';
parse_str($crop_cords, $parsed);

print_r($parsed);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/vqVeQ)**.

Comment: Brilliant...never used that before.  Works great! Thanks

Comment: I would use several variables in the URL (or inputs as ngen advised). But otherwise, `parse_str` is the way to go. **It is of utmost importance to pass that 2nd parameter, otherwise your website could be vulnerable to several types of security issues.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse the string as if it were the querystring:

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_POST['crop_cords'], $params);
```